# Shipping address same as Billing

Tags: forms, checkbox, show-hide

I have a form, the Shipping address needs to be hidden, when you uncheck the checkbox (Same Shipping address as Billing address) the shippingaddress fields gets visible. Also the billing address needs to be filled as same as the shippingaddress unless the checkbox is unchecked.

So short said, copy billing address to shippingaddress and shippingaddress not visible, when unchecked, shippingaddress gets visible and fields are empty.

I made a start here;
Hope someone can help me out!

http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/P7RhF/3/

```
<form>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
      <label>Firstname <abbr class="required" title="verplicht">*</abbr></label><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstname:required" id="firstname" />
    </p>

    <h2>Deliver address</h2>

    <p id="shiptobilling" class="form-row">
      Same as Shipping <input type="checkbox" onclick="SetBilling(this.checked);" /> 
    </p>

    <div class="shipping_address" style="display:none;">
        <p class="form-row form-row-first">
          <label>Voornaam <abbr class="required" title="verplicht"></abbr></label><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="deliver_firstname" id="deliver_firstname" />
        </p>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Checkout" name="checkout" />

</form>
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetBilling(checked) {
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementById('firstname').value = document.getElementById('deliver_firstname').value; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('firstname').value = ''; 
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the change display style of shipping_address div to block to make it visible.

```
function SetBilling(checked) {
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementById('deliveryaddres').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('deliver_firstname').value = ''; 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('deliveryaddres').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('deliver_firstname').value = document.getElementById('firstname').value; 
    }
}
```

To make it easier I added id to the required div:

```
<div id="deliveryaddres" class="shipping_address" style="display:none;">
```

See the working code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P7RhF/4/

Comment: Hey thanks allot, 

Almost there, when I fill the billing address field, it needs to fill the shipping address too. So when I submit the form, the shippingfields are the same (when checked). When uncheck the checkbox, the fields need to be empty so the visitor can add the different shipping address. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: If you don't mind some jQuery you can use this code to mirror input field $('#firstname').bind('keypress blur', function() { $('#deliver_firstname').val($(this).val()); });  See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/P7RhF/10/

Comment: When I test your jsfiddle, enter my name and then uncheck, it's not empty. It needs to copy the name, when I uncheck the field are empty.

Answer (score 1):

u can try this one(if u can change ur btn type submit to button)

```
$("#chkSameAsBilling").live("click", function () {
        var isBillingShown = $("#chkSameAsBilling").is(":checked");
        if (isBillingShown) {
            $("#txtBillingAddress").val($("#lblShippingAddress").text());
            $("#txtBillingAddress").add().attr("style", "display: none;");

        }
        else {
            $("#txtBillingAddress").show();

        }
    });
    function SetBilling(checked) {
        if (checked) {
            document.getElementById('firstname').value = document.getElementById('deliver_firstname').value;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('firstname').value = '';
        }
    }
    $(".btn").live("click", function () {
        alert($("#txtBillingAddress").val());
    });
```

the html:

```
<form>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
      <label>Firstname <abbr class="required" title="verplicht">*</abbr></label><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstname:required" id="firstname" />
    </p>

    <h2>Deliver address</h2>

        <label id="lblShippingAddress" style="display:none;">Bangladesh</label><br/>
    <label for="billingAddress">Billing Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtBillingAddress"/><br/>

    <p id="shiptobilling" class="form-row">

      Same as Shipping <input type="checkbox" id="chkSameAsBilling" onclick="SetBilling(this.checked);"/> 
    </p>

    <div class="shipping_address" style="display:none;">
        <p class="form-row form-row-first">
          <label>Voornaam <abbr class="required" title="verplicht"></abbr></label><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="deliver_firstname" id="deliver_firstname" />
        </p>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Checkout" name="checkout" />

</form>
```

Comment: I can't change it to button, the form won't do noting then :(

I have changed the fiddle but it doesn't work yet, http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/P7RhF/9/

it just needs to fill the same content to the shippingfields, but when I uncheck it needs to be empty. I'm no coder.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");  
    var textShip = document.getElementById("ShippingAd");
    var areaShip = document.getElementById("AreaAd");
    var textBil = document.getElementById("BillingAd");
    var area2Bil = document.getElementById("Area2Ad");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
          textBil.value=textShip.value; 
          area2Bil.value=areaShip.value;
    } else {
          textBil.value="";
          area2Bil.value="";
    }
  }
```

```html
<!--shipping add same as billing add-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>shipping Address</p>
    <textarea id="ShippingAd"></textarea>  
  <p>Area</p>
    <textarea id="AreaAd"></textarea>  
    <br/>
  
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
    <label for="myCheck">Same as shipping Address:</label>
  
    <p>billing Address</p>
    <textarea id="BillingAd"></textarea><br/>   
  
    <p>Area</p>
    <textarea id="Area2Ad"></textarea>  
</body>
</html>
```